# State Machine and Qt Designer

Tags: qt, state-machine

I am trying to modify the Qt's State Machine frame work example. I have created a QWidget in Qt designer and added a label and button. Here is my code

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    setupStateMachine();
}

void MainWindow:: setupStateMachine()
{
    QStateMachine machine;
    QState *s1 = new QState();
    QState *s2 = new QState();
    QState *s3 = new QState();

    s1->assignProperty(ui->label, "text", "In state s1");
    s2->assignProperty(ui->label, "text", "In state s2");
    s3->assignProperty(ui->label, "text", "In state s3");

    s1->addTransition(this->ui->button, SIGNAL(clicked()), s2);
    s2->addTransition(this->ui->button, SIGNAL(clicked()), s3);
    s3->addTransition(this->ui->button, SIGNAL(clicked()), s1);

    machine.addState(s1);
    machine.addState(s2);
    machine.addState(s3);
    machine.setInitialState(s1);

    machine.start();

    qDebug() << "State Machine Created";
}
```

It is running but clicking the button is not changing the label text. Where I am making mistake? I am new in Qt , please excuse me if it is a silly question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `QStateMachine` object goes out of scope and gets deleted at the end of the function. 
You should allocate it dynamically:

```
QStateMachine *machine = new QStateMachine(this);
```